# Transition does not work on :before

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a navigation bar for my portfolio page. Now when I hover one div element, the :before element should extend it's width in 0.4s seconds. But this is not the case, the :before just pops up with no transition. Hope someone of you knows the problem. Here is my source code.

```css
.header__navigation {
  display: flex;
}
.header__navigation .nav {
  margin: 0 30px;
}
.header__navigation .nav > div {
  position: relative;
}
.header__navigation .nav > div:before {
  transition: width 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.header__navigation .nav > div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header__navigation .nav > div:hover:before {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header">
 <div class="header__text"></div>
 <div class="header__navigation">
  <div class="nav" routerLink="home" (click)="scrollTop()">
   <span>Home</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav" routerLink="about" (click)="scrollTo(heading)">
   <span>About</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav" routerLink="about">
   <span>Contact</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML also, so we can see a [working demonstration of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added it! Sorry im not very familiar with stackoverflow :(

Comment: `.header__navigation .nav > div` matches no elements in your HTML.

Comment: Please delete your question after you fixed your problems. It is of no value for anyone researching Stackoverflow in the future as it simply is caused by a wrong selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some success by setting an initial width of zero.
This gives the `transition` distinct values to animate.

Also, there are no elements in your HTML that match `.nav > div`.
I changed the CSS to `.nav > span`.

I also moved `height:2px` out of the `:hover` definition.
This allows the transition to work on both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

```css
.header__navigation {
  display: flex;
}

.header__navigation .nav {
  margin: 0 30px;
}

.header__navigation .nav>span {
  position: relative;
}

.header__navigation .nav>span:before {
  transition: width 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: tomato;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 0;
  height:2px;
}

.header__navigation .nav>span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__navigation .nav>span:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header">
  <div class="header__navigation">
    <div class="nav">
      <span>Home</span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <span>About</span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <span>Contact</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it seems changing `div` to `span` was the only this necessary here.

Comment: Worked perfect, Thank you! :)